# how to make restriction on bootstrap slider?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, jquery-ui-slider

hi friends I want to make restriction on slider that, current can't be less than start and more than end. or start cant be more that end and ....

here is my javascript code,

`$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#slider").slider({
              animate: true,
              value:0,
              min: 0,
              max: 10,
              step: 1,
              slide: function(event, ui) {
                  update(1,ui.value); //changed
              }
          });

```
      $("#slider2").slider({
          animate: true,
          value:0,
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
          step: 1,
          slide: function(event, ui) {
              update(2,ui.value); //changed
          }
      });

      $("#slider3").slider({
          animate: true,
          value:0,
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
          step: 1,
          slide: function(event, ui) {
              update(3,ui.value); //changed
          }
      });

      //Added, set initial value.
      $("#start").val(0);
      $("#current").val(0);
      $("#end").val(0);

      update();
  });

  //changed. now with parameter
  function update(slider,val) {
    //changed. Now, directly take value from ui.value. if not set (initial, will use current value.)
    var $start = slider == 1?val:$("#start").val();
    var $current = slider == 2?val:$("#current").val();
    var $end = slider == 3?val:$("#end").val();

     $( "#start" ).val($start);         
     $( "#current" ).val($current);        
     $( "#end" ).val($end);

     $('#slider a').html('<label> '+$start+' </label>');
     $('#slider3 a').html('<label> '+$end+' </label>');
     $('#slider2 a').html('<label> '+$current+' </label>');
  }`
```

and I have added this part to it, but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#slider").slider({
          animate: true,
          value:0,
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
          step: 1,
          slide: function(event, ui) {
              update(1,ui.value); //changed
          }
      });
      var min1 = $("#slider").min();

      $("#slider2").slider({
          animate: true,
          value:0,
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
          values: [min1, 5]
          step: 1,
          slide: function(event, ui) {
              update(2,ui.value); //changed
          }
      });

      $("#slider3").slider({
          animate: true,
          value:0,
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
          step: 1,
          slide: function(event, ui) {
              update(3,ui.value); //changed
          }
      });

      //Added, set initial value.
      $("#start").val(0);
      $("#current").val(0);
      $("#end").val(0);

      update();
  });

  //changed. now with parameter
  function update(slider,val) {
    //changed. Now, directly take value from ui.value. if not set (initial, will use current value.)
    var $start = slider == 1?val:$("#start").val();
    var $current = slider == 2?val:$("#current").val();
    var $end = slider == 3?val:$("#end").val();

     $( "#start" ).val($start);         
     $( "#current" ).val($current);        
     $( "#end" ).val($end);

     $('#slider a').html('<label> '+$start+' </label>');
     $('#slider3 a').html('<label> '+$end+' </label>');
     $('#slider2 a').html('<label> '+$current+' </label>');
  }
```

could you please help me to do the restriction?

thanks